# How update column with 4 columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-update

I need like this. Update E with col A, col B, col C and col D like "abcd"

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |    E   |
======================================
  |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  abcd  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like string concatenation, which is not standard across databases.  Here are some methods:

```
update t
    set E = concat(a, b, c, d);

update t
    set E = a || b || c || d;

update t
    set E = a + b + c + d;
```

The first is the standard.  It should work in MySQL and Postgres.  The second is also commonly used, and works in Oracle, Postgres, and DB2.  The third is for SQL Server and Sybase.

Comment: There *is* a standard for string concatenation in SQL. It's `||`. Microsoft/Sybase and MySQL simply chose to ignore it.